# When does a new question not show up in the Top Questions list?

Tags: support, homepage

Just curious - I asked a new question - [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688130/open-python-repl-in-current-solution-or-project-or-open-cmd-prompt-with-python) (though I'm not pimping for votes or even views) and went to the ["all questions list"](https://stackoverflow.com/) (you know, the front page, though I guess it is called "Top Questions") and it didn't show up.  I refreshed several times over a period of a few minutes and - nope - didn't show up.

So what are the criteria for when a question shows up there?  I thought all new questions, plus edited questions, plus answered questions, plus modified questions, etc., showed up there.  But maybe not.  Maybe *that's* why it's called "Top Questions" not "All Questions"?

Comment: Are the tags on the post of your Question on your "Watched Tags" list?

Comment: @Scratte - at least two of them, plus, I went to that list in a private browser window and it also didn't show there.  Plus none of the tags are on my "ignore" list.

Comment: I get a login page in a private browser. But apart from that. I put python and visual-studio-2019 in my  "Watched Tags" list and I don't see it on the front page either. I can't explain that.

Comment: @Scratte - in the private browser I get the oft-complained-about-on-meta page that appears to be mostly promoting stack{exchange,overflow} but if you scroll down and find and click on the stackoverflow logo near the mid-left you get the top questions page.

Comment: (Note to teams users: You will be seeing 'All Questions' where it was supposed to be 'Top Questions' and 'Public Questions' where it was supposed to be 'All Questions'. Just wanted to let you know if you get confused like I did)

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but I'll occasionally find that the search results will lag behind actual posts, presumably due to a problem with whatever process indexes new content. Usually it's only behind by an hour or two—though a few weeks ago it wasn't showing new content for 18+ hours. What I don't know, however, is whether or not "Top Questions" uses that same index as the search results.