# Why is 'Top Questions' replaced with 'All Questions' on the homepage for teams users?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, homepage

I was just reading *[When does a new question not show up in the Top Questions list?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410639/11573842)* and I was confused as to what they were asking when they said *'Maybe that's why it's called "Top Questions" not "All Questions"?'* because, for me, a teams user, the [homepage](//stackoverflow.com) reads 'All Questions' and not 'Top Questions'.

See for yourself:

[image: Screenshot. I see All Questions instead of Top Questions]

Normally the home page says 'Top Questions' and [stackoverflow.com/questions](//stackoverflow.com/questions) says 'All Questions'. For me, they say 'All Questions' and 'Public Questions' respectively.

The latter of the two I can understand but why change the former? And if you are going to change it then it is probably not a good idea to change it to something that is the heading of another page... I feel like this is bound to cause confusion. Is this a bug? Or is it intentional? If this is intentional then can it be changed to 'Top Questions' for consistency sake? (I know that 'Top Questions' itself isn't a great heading but still)